# Como utilizar o error_reporting

Tags: php

Eu estou tendo um problema na minha página há algum tempo. Revirei minha `Model`, `Controller` e `View` e nada. Simplesmente
a tela fica branca (porém não aparece erro algum) e nada faz funcionar.

Quero saber qual seria a melhor forma de encontrar esse problema. 
Seria com `error_reporting`? Se sim, como utilizo ele?

Comment: Aproveite para ver esse e alguns outros erros comuns no [wiki tag do php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) além de outras dicas e materiais sugeridos para estudo. :)

Comment: Qual framework está usando? Por que se não é meio dificil de explicar como usar algo sem dizer aonde coloca-lo. Talvez ajude se postar o Model, View e o Controller.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Estou utilizando o CodeIgniter

Comment: Chara, postar algum código deve ser relevante.

Comment: O código é enorme, fica meio complicado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Esses dois comandos podem resolver sua questão. Eles devem ser as primeiras linhas da aplicação.

```
ini_set('display_errors', true); // Configura o PHP para mostrar os erros
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Altera o handler de erros para mostrar todos os tipos
```

error_reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

ini_set: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: Não entendi a parte de criar o arquivo, e porque. Poderia me explicar melhor? Estou começando nesse ramo, e sei muito pouco.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php O phpinfo irá mostrar todas as configurações do seu PHP, é vital você entender como as coisas estão configuradas.

Comment: Também não vejo a necessidade do phpinfo para a resposta, já que de qualquer maneira você está usando o `ini_set`.

Comment: De acordo. resposta editada.

Comment: @GêBender Onde devo colocar este código?

Comment: @GuilhermeWermann As alterações se darão dessas linhas para baixo, logo, coloque-as o mais no início possível em sua aplicação para dar o máximo de cobertura e mostrar o erro que vc procura.

Comment: Obrigado! @GêBender